# Releasing new changes to the active browser sessions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react application (it is not a server side rendered application) that is used by many of the users. We do a monthly release, how do I ensure to release changes to the active browser sessions of users.

Currently we ask our users to do a hard refresh of a browser tab to ensure they get a new bundle.js from the server.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is request a script file everytime the app loads, in the following manner:

```
// your main.js

loadScript(`http://yourserver.com/updateRequired.js?q=${Math.random()}`)
```

The above Math.random() makes sure this script is never loaded from cache. Whenever you want to perform a hard reload of the application on user's browsers, change the updateRequired.js file on the server from blank file to:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('version') != 'your_latest_version_here') {
   localStorage.setItem('version') = 'your_latest_version_here';
   window.location.reload(true); // performs a hard reload
}
```

Comment: request a script file everytime the app loads? 

My browser session is already active, and a release happened. How will this line of code "loadScript(`http://yourserver.com/updateRequired.js?q=${Math.random()}`)" even get executed?

Comment: If you want to perform real time reload, you should open a websocket to server and send a message to all connected clients to reload the app. JS will pick up this message and reload the page for you

Comment: I needed an example for doing that.